# How do I grab data from a csv/excel file into my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, puppeteer, webautomation

Im using puppeteer to automate doing a form, I want to directly grab data from a csv file and input into the form. How do I go about doing that?
The CSV file is :
`FirstName,Number,Address,Country,meliz,123,High Road,US`.

Form Link: https://forms.gle/UUQUgTm9tpmrGSnF8

Update: Below is the code I used to convert to JSON

```
const csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json')

const json = csvToJson.getJsonFromCsv("Book1.csv");

for(let i=0; i<json.length;i++){
  console.log(json[i]);
 }
```

This is the result

```
{   FirstName: 'meliz',   Number: '123',   Address: 'High Road',   Country: 'US' }
```

I want to get a specific value e.g FirstName

How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the CSV file into JSON and then flow that object into your code.

```js
const csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');

const fileInputName = 'myInputFileName.csv';

const json = csvToJson.getJsonFromCsv("myInputFile.csv"); // you can use this json into your code.

// looping on the json
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  console.log(json[i]);
  console.log(json[i].FirstName);
  console.log(json[i].Number);
  console.log(json[i].Address);
  console.log(json[i].Country);
}
```

[csv-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json) this package will help you in converting your csv to json.

Comment: how would I grab like 1 specific value using this method? @rohanraj

Comment: you can loop on the JSON object. updated the answer for your reference.

Comment: this is the results I got, however e.g I need just the value of FirstName, and then from there input the vale into a variable? how would I do it
`{
  FirstName: 'meliz',
  Number: '123',
  Address: 'High Road',
  Country: 'US'
}`

Comment: updated the answer for your reference. @meliz